# How can I generate a series of date ranges that fall between a start date and end date?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to generate an array of all the time ranges that fall within 4 pm-9 pm between a start and end date

```
start_date          | end_date
----------------------------------------
2020-11-01 16:30:00 | 2020-11-03 18:30:00
```

The query should be able to turn the above table into:

```
row | start_date          | end_date
------------------------------------------------
1   | 2020-11-01 16:30:00 | 2020-11-01 21:00:00
------------------------------------------------
2   | 2020-11-02 16:00:00 | 2020-11-02 21:00:00
------------------------------------------------
3   | 2020-11-03 16:00:00 | 2020-11-03 18:30:00
```

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to approach this?

Comment: What if start_date is `2020-11-01 15:00:00`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
with input as (
  select '2020-11-01 16:30:00'::timestamptz as start_date,
         '2020-11-03 18:30:00'::timestamptz as end_date
)
select row_number() over (order by ddate) as row,
       case 
         when     start_date::date = ddate  
              and start_date > ddate + interval '16 hours' 
           then start_date
         else ddate + interval '16 hours'
       end as start_date,
       case
         when     end_date::date = ddate
              and end_date < ddate + interval '21 hours'
           then end_date
         else ddate + interval '21 hours'
       end as end_date 
  from input
       cross join lateral 
         generate_series(
           case 
             when start_date::time > '21:00' then start_date::date + interval '1 day'
             else start_date::date
           end, 
           case 
             when end_date::time < '16:00' then end_date::date - interval '1 day'
             else end_date::date
           end, 
           interval '1 day') as gs(ddate)
;
┌─────┬────────────────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ row │       start_date       │        end_date        │
├─────┼────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│   1 │ 2020-11-01 16:30:00-05 │ 2020-11-01 21:00:00-05 │
│   2 │ 2020-11-02 16:00:00-05 │ 2020-11-02 21:00:00-05 │
│   3 │ 2020-11-03 16:00:00-05 │ 2020-11-03 18:30:00-05 │
└─────┴────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I'd simply generate series over hours not over days. So you can filter them directly. See my solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you use generate_series with hours instead of days as in the solution of @MikeOrganek, you can filter them directly. Start and end hours should be "complete hours", which can be achieved using `date_trunc()`. Because `date_trunc` cuts the final minutes of the end date, it makes sense, to create the series an hour more; this is why an hour is added in the example.

Finally `GROUP BY` date and give out the `MIN` and `MAX` time. With `least()` and `greatest()` you can adjust the edge cases.

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c21da98a9dd95706d7b86e3628521b2c)

```
SELECT
    GREATEST(MIN(gs), start_date) as start_time,
    LEAST(MAX(gs), end_date) as end_time
FROM
    t,
    generate_series(
        date_trunc('hour', start_date), 
        date_trunc('hour', end_date) + interval '1 hour',
        interval '1 hour'
    ) as gs
WHERE gs::time >= '16:00:00' and gs::time <= '21:00:00'
GROUP BY start_date, end_date, gs::date
ORDER BY gs::date
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `generate_series()` with a one day interval and construct the time part depending on the value of the time in start/end date for the first and last day.

```
with from_to (start_date, end_date) as (
 values (timestamp '2020-11-01 16:30:00', timestamp '2020-11-03 18:30:00')
)
select g.nr as row, 
       g.d::date + case 
                      when g.d::date = start_date::date and start_date::time > time '16:00' then start_date::time
                      else time '16:00'
                   end as start_date,
       g.d::date + case 
                     when g.d::date = end_date::date and end_date::time < time '21:00' then end_date::time
                     else time '21:00'
                  end as end_date
from from_to 
  cross join generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 day') with ordinality as g(d,nr)
order by g.nr;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8c02df7dbf284185ea567e43be3f6bb9)